# can't change default many to many widget in django form

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi I have a many to many field:

```
class Seeking(models.Model):  
    entity = models.OneToOneField(Entity)
    company_type = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyTypeChoice)
```

I have this form that uses field:

```
class SeekingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Seeking
        widgets = {'m2m_field': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}
        exclude = (
                  'entity',
                  )

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

         super(SeekingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields["company_type"].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
```

The widget still renders as a multi select box.  I am using django 10.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify a custom widget for a field, use the widgets attribute of the inner Meta class. This should be a dictionary mapping **field names** to widget classes or instances.

```
class SeekingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Seeking
        widgets = {'company_type': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple() }
        exclude = (
              'entity',
              )
```